# Azure Traditional Load Balancer VS Azure Application Gateway response latency?

Tags: networking, windows-server-2012-r2, azure, load-balancing, azure-networking

Environment Details:
I have an application hosted in two azure environments for two clients. The application contains ASP.NET web API backend and Angular Frontend. Both applications hosted on two web servers (Windows VM). I'm using LB in the first environment (Environment 1) and using AGW in the second environment (Environment 2).

Problem:
The issue that I'm having is, environment 1 API request response time is faster than the environment 2. Below is the screenshot of the browser inspect window for the same request.

According to the timing tab, environment 1 has a fast response time than environment 2.

Question:
My question is whether this response time difference due to using LB and AGW?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AGW is a reverse proxy, it works at layer 7 instead of layer 4; it actually has to terminate the HTTP(S) connections from the clients and reopen them to the servers, instead of simply forwarding packets. Of course it's going to be slower.

That said, you should also verify that your AGW sizing is appropriate to your workload; but in any case, it will always be at least a bit slower than a load balancer.